# knockout.js utils.arrayFilter property is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Hi guys I am trying to add a filter system to a project that allows users to filter a set of locations based on what they type in an input field and whatis happening is that it is auto filling with 5 sets of objects and also what ever the user inputs, doesnt really do anything and that code i got what from the website.

```
self.pointsFilter = ko.computed(function(){
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.pointsList(), function(pointItem){
      return pointItem.done = true;
    })
  })
```

Answer (score 2):

The expression *"return pointItem.done = true;"* is wrong. If you want to get only done points you have to **use the == operator**. And double check whether pointItem.done is not observable. If it is you should add brackets *"pointItem.done()"* to get the value.

Comment: That's absolutely right, even you could  just return pointItem.done